# Using sed to find a word and replace another word

Tags: sed, replace

I have a word like "mode   v"  in a file. I want to replace it to "mode sv". However all my efforts failed as there is space after mode

Comment: looks like i found the answer. sed 's/^mode .*$/mode sv/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `sed` do the search and replacement like so.

```
$ sed 's/mode v/mode sv/g'
```

#### Example

Say I have this sample file:

```
$ cat afile.txt 
mode v modev mode v
blah
blah blah modev mode
blah
modev mode v
```

I can use `sed` to search/replace this file and preserve a backup like so:

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/mode v/mode sv/g' afile.txt
```

I now have 2 files:

```
$ ls -ltr | grep afile
-rw-rw-r--. 1 slm slm      64 Sep 23 20:13 afile.txt.bak
-rw-rw-r--. 1 slm slm      67 Sep 23 20:15 afile.txt
```

With the changes made to the origianl:

```
$ cat afile.txt
mode sv modev mode sv
blah
blah blah modev mode
blah
modev mode sv
```

**NOTE:** If you need it to be a guaranteed word boundary you can suffix the `mode v` in the search with a `\b`.

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/mode v\b/mode sv/g' afile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution from comment works only if mode is the very first word in the line and replaces everything after "mode " with "sv". From your question I believe this is not your intention.
There is no reason to complicate things, simple

```
sed 's/mode /mode s/g'
```

should work. Alternatively

```
sed s/"mode "/"mode s"/g
```